# Mongoose schema definition design

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, pug, mean-stack

I'm in the process of getting familiar with the MEAN Stack. In this process i'm designing a lab app, to learn the different aspects of the stack. Right now, i'm at the point of defining a schema in mongoose.

The app is basically a set of `locations`, with `lessons` and `students` per `location`. And per `lesson` a set of `students` who are assigned to the `lesson`.

The `lessons` are given on different days so I need to store a `lesson` to a `location`, and to a `day` of the week. And when adding a `student`, I should be able to assign it to one or more `lessons`. I also want to be able for instance, to query a `location`, query the days, and per day if there is a `lesson`, I want to display the `lessons` and the `students` attending this `lesson`.

This is my design schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var studentNames = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: {type: String, required: true},
  lastName: {type: String, required: true},
  telephone: {type: String},
  emailAddress: {type: String},
  isMember: {type: Boolean},
  lessons: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'lessonnames'}]
});

var lessonNames = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String},
  startTime: {type: String},
  endTime: {type: String},
  day: {type: String}
});

var locationNames = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true},
  address: {type: String},
  lessons: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'lessonnames'}],
  lessonDays: [{
    Monday: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'lessonnames'}],
    Tuesday: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'lessonnames'}],
    Wednesday: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'lessonnames'}],
    Thursday: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'lessonnames'}],
    Friday: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'lessonnames'}],
    Saturday: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'lessonnames'}],
    Sunday: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'lessonnames'}]
  }]
});

mongoose.model('studentnames', studentNames);
mongoose.model('lessonnames', lessonNames);
mongoose.model('locationnames', locationNames);
```

Question, is this the right schema design to be able to do the things i want to do ?

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT:

As I look at this, shouldn't i include a ObjectId ref in the lessonNames to studentNames, so I can see which student is part of the specific lesson?

Comment: How many `Lessons` can a `Location` have, and how many `Lessons` can a `Student` enrol in?

Comment: You should create the lessonNames model after studentNames as studentNames model references that of lessonNames

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera, I want about 4/5 locations, and the amount of lessons depends but i think i will implement about 5 lessons each day. The student should be allowed to follow as many lessons as the student would like(if lessons don't overlap off course)

Comment: @ZeMoon thanks, I will think about that in my final version :)